# Saving data structure to a text file

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to implement a save system which allows me to save the user entered data of the "packet" structure that the user entered in the switch statement. Each record entered is stored in a single file separated via lines in plain text. It should also prompt the user what they would like to name the file, then the program should indicate how many records have been saved to the file, finally if no name is entered for the save file it should go back to the main menu.

as you can see from the void save function at the bottom, i have tried to implement this save system but when i run the program and choose S to save the records to the file it simply crashes the program after I enter a name for the file name. So if anyone could help me with this, that would be great.

```
struct packet{
    int source;
    int destination;
    int type;               // Varibles for the structure
    int port;
    char data[50];
    char * filename;
};

void save(int, struct packet*); //function to save the records stored to a file
int main ()
{
struct packet s[50];         //Array for structure input
char choice;
int NetworkPacket = 0, ii = 0;
int recordCount = 0;
struct packet *records;
struct packet *temp;
records = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
```

case statement for choosing to save the file

```
 case 'S':
            system("cls"); //clear the screen
            save(NetworkPacket, records); //S was chosen so use the Save function
 break;
```

the save function

```
 void save(int rCount, struct packet *records){
  FILE *recordFile;                 //file handle
  char fileName[30] = { '\0'};      //string to store the file name
  int i;

  puts("Enter a filename to save the records :");   //ask the user for the filename
  scanf("%s", fileName);                            //store the filename: data input should be checked
                                                    //here in your program

  //try and open the file for writing and react accordingly if there is a problem
  if((recordFile = fopen(fileName,"w"))==NULL){
      printf("Couldn't open the file: %s\n",fileName);
      exit(1);
  }
  else{ //the file opened so print the records array of packets to it
      for(i=0;i<rCount;i++){
          fprintf(recordFile,"%04d %04d %04d %04d %s\n",
                  records[i].source,
                  records[i].destination,
                  records[i].type,
                  records[i].port,
                  records[i].port,
                  records[i].data);
      }
      fclose(recordFile);   //close the file
  }

}
```

Comment: Build a debug version, and run in a debugger. It will stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine and walk up the function call stack. When you're walking up the call stack to the place the crash happens in your code, you will be able to examine values of variables.

Comment: Things to look for before that, might be the value of `rCount` (`NetworkPacket`) and making sure that you have enough allocated memory for the `records` pointer (right now you seem to only allocate a single `packet` structure).

Comment: Are you sure records[i].data is a null terminated string?

Comment: fprintf mismatch argument.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more %d modifier required in the format string - there are five ints but only four %d's

```
fprintf(recordFile,"%04d %04d %04d %04d %04d %s\n",
                                        ^^^^
```